# Zeroes of $s+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s\ln n} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

Where are the solutions of the equations

> $$s+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^s\ln n}=0\quad \text{and}\quad   s+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s\ln n}=0 ?$$

Since the functions on the LHS are the integral of the zeta function and the alternating zeta function, it might make a difference if one assumes RH or not.

I am considering zeroes in the entire complex plane , hence after analytic continuation.
Although I am mainly interested in the zeross with $\operatorname{Re} s>-1$.

Is it true that all non real zeroes are in the critical strip $0<\operatorname{Re} s<1$ apart from at most a finite amount ?

I wondered if integral representations are insightful.

It is clear that for $\operatorname{Re} s>\alpha$ there is no solution when the positive real $\alpha$ is sufficiently large.

I assume these integrals of these zeta functions cannot be expressed as an infinite product over primes, is that true ?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Roots $\approx$ zeroes $\ne$ solutions.